# PGP and the Cryptography Application Block

Tags: cryptography, enterprise-library, pgp

I just had a request to add PGP support to a web application and web service that I'm developing.  I currently am using the Enterprise Library, and would like to use the Cryptography Application Block (CAB) that I'm already using, but I can't find any information on supporting PGP with the Enterprise Library's CAB.  I would figure as much as both of these technologies are used, and the fact that the CAB is extensible, someone would have provided some support for this.  Is there something I'm overlooking, or can someone provide links on using the CAB with PGP.

I don't know all the details as of yet as to why they want to use PGP, but I'm assuming that blocks of information are going to be encrypted with a PGP public key and posted to the Web service, so I would need to use a private key programatically on the server side to decrypt to get to the information being posted.  It sounds like a horrible idea, but my part is not the planning, only the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crypto block API isn't set up for public key algorithms, unfortunately. It handles hashing and symmetric (single key) algorithms only.

Comment: really?  That's unfortunate.  I figure asymmetric cryptography would be supported by any crypto framework.

Comment: The crypto block was written as an easier to use wrapper around the .NET 1.0 crypto features. Those features didn't include public key crypto, so the block doesn't either.

Comment: I've done some serious studying trying to find out if I could even hack in support for asymmetric crypto.  And I'll agree, you are absolutely correct, I'll have to look for another solution to providing PGP support in my application besides the enterprise library. Thanks for the information, I'm rather upset that it doesn't provide a good solution for me, I like working with the Enterprise Application Blocks.